# Catch and try en Javascript VS try and except en Python

Tags: javascript, python

Está el concepto de bloques de declaraciones que pueden generar una excepción.
En el caso de Javascript se tiene el
*Try and catch*, como ejemplo:

```
let num = 1;
try {
  num.toUpperCase();   // You cannot convert a number to upper case
}
catch(err) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = err.name;
}
```

y el Fetch:

```
async function getText(file) {
  let myObject = await fetch(file);
  let myText = await myObject.text();
  myDisplay(myText);
}
```

En python se tienen las excepciones, que sería *try and except*.
Un ejemplo:

```
# import module sys to get the type of exception

    import sys
    
    randomList = ['a', 0, 2]
    
    for entry in randomList:
        try:
            print("The entry is", entry)
            r = 1/int(entry)
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print("Oops!", e.__class__, "occurred.")
            print("Next entry.")
            print()
    print("The reciprocal of", entry, "is", r)
```

Mi pregunta, en pocas palabras: ¿estas formas tanto en Javascript como en Python trabajan de manera similar o hay alguna otra forma?
¿Hay diferencias entre try and catch y Fetch?

Comment: [Try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) y [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/fetch) no es lo mismo (JS). ¿Cuál trata de ser tu pregunta?

Comment: Es el mismo concepto que existe en distintas implementaciones. En Cobol tienes ON ERROR (para instrucciones, no bloques). En Basic el ON ERROR cubre todo el programa. La idea es separar el proceso normal del manejo de errores y anomalis.

Comment: @padaleiana cuales son las diferencias entre ambos

Comment: interesante muchas gracias por la info! @CandidMoe